# Adding an optional "global" keyword to lua 5.2 source

Tags: c, lua

I'd like to modify the lua 5.2 source code to allow for an optional "global" keyword to precede global variable declarations. Has any done this or does anyone know how to do this (safely)? And yes I am aware that variables are global by default and that this would be purely syntactic sugar.

To be clear, adding custom keywords of existing types is straight forward. The part I'm at a loss for is how to safely edit the parser (via the 5.2 C source code) so that it discards or ignores the new "global" keyword.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: To make global declarations explicit and easier to spot as well as to guard against accidental declarations.

Comment: Why not just do _G.variable = value? There really isn't such thing as a global in lua. _G is just the default environment (lookup table) which can be changed with setfenv. Try not to think of lua as a C-like language. You are just in various scopes within tables when you access variables, where each have explicit instructions set by metamethods on what to do exactly. _G just happens to be the default when a value cannot be found in that scope.

Comment: Give an example of a short complete code that has this declaration.

Comment: @Alundaio, thanks but that's all obvious and not at all pertinent to my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. First I appended a new token TK_GLOBAL to the end of the RESERVED enum.

Then in luaX_init() I added...

```
ts = luaS_new(L, "global");
luaS_fix(ts);
ts->tsv.reserved = cast_byte(TK_GLOBAL+1-FIRST_RESERVED);
```

And finally in the statement() function I added...

```
case TK_GLOBAL:
   luaX_next(ls);
break;
```

As far as I can tell it works. Hopefully it's safe.

Answer (score 0):

See this discussion for details and a proposed patch (against 5.3): http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2018-07/msg00422.html. It uses a different (non-keyword based) approach, but should be a good starting point.

Comment: I'd prefer a quick and dirty solution, something along the lines of the "global" keyword gets interpreted as whitespace or is somehow otherwise stripped away and discarded by the parser.

Comment: @user2418731, it's very easy to write a token filter for that. Try ltokenp.

Comment: Please add the gist of the discussion here - just the salient points - so if the link dies again the answer is still useful.

Comment: @ChrisF, I'm not sure how to summarize it, as it covers 13 questions and answers just in the main post (plus follow-ups) and most of them are relevant. I can add a link to the actual implementation referenced there (https://gist.github.com/Egor-Skriptunoff/c2d1bd8b5348ab3ed59991a9dda7ed5c), but that's probably all that can be done. I think the information is still useful, so it would be ideal to preserve it for as long as the link is valid (and it's "controlled" by the Lua team to some degree).